# "Token is expired or invalid" when trying to server-side validate Huawei subscription

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

I'm trying to do a server-side verification of Huawei subscription, but currently I'm stuck at verification part

1. Im successfully obtain access_token from [this url](https://oauth-login.cloud.huawei.com/oauth2/v2/token)

2. Do a base64encode UTF-8 format of string 'APPAT:my_access_token'
3. Then I'm trying to get purchaseDetails from https://subscr-drcn.iap.hicloud.com/sub/applications/v2/purchases/get. Im sending subscriptionId and purchaseToken in json format and base64encoded access_token in Authorization ('Basic my_access_token') header and Content-Type=application/json;charset=UTF-8
4. Every time I get this response:

   {
   "responseCode": "6",
   "responseMessage": "Token is expired or invalid"
   }

Searching for this message didn't help. What can be the problem with it? Is it invalid purchaseToken or invalid accessToken?

Please help me with this, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check as follows:

1. Check your access_token: obtain the access_token and print it.
2. When referencing Base64, refer to  `import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;`
3. Add to the header correctly:

```
* Construct an Authorization field in the request header.
*
* @param appAt App-level access token.
* @return headers Return the request header.
*/
    public static Map<String, String> buildAuthorization(String appAt) {
        String oriString = MessageFormat.format("APPAT:{0}", appAt);
        String authorization =
        MessageFormat.format("Basic {0}", Base64.encodeBase64String(oriString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("Authorization", authorization);
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        return headers;
    }
    /**
```

For more details, see [docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Examples-V5/server-sample-code-0000001050145549-V5).

Comment: Thank you for server sample code! Im using Python so it helped me a lot. The problem was with generating access token, but now everything works like a charm. Thanks again!